# Alleged quote by Habermas in original. "Science is the ideology of late capitalism." Where to find it?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, quote

M. Bunge in his book "Evaluating Philosophies" makes the following statement:

> Scientism has been explicitly opposed by dogmatists and obscurantists of all stripes, such as the neoliberal ideologist Friedrich von Hayek and the "critical theorist" Jürgen Habermas, a ponderous writer who managed to amalgamate Hegel, Marx, and Freud, and decreed that "science is the ideology of late capitalism."

Unfortunately the book gives no sources for the quote by Habermas.
As I understood it Habermas said that "science is the ideology of late capitalism." Since Habermas writes in German where can I find this exact quote.

Comment: I'm not sure that Bunge is reporting a direct quote, rather "science is the ideology of late capitalism" is a summary of Habermas' position. His thoughts on the subject are set out in *[Technik und Wissenschaft als „Ideologie“](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technik_und_Wissenschaft_als_%E2%80%9EIdeologie%E2%80%9C)* (1968), English translation in *Toward a Rational Society* (1970), see especially Chapter 6.